# Slideshow stopped working when I put a gallery in

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slideshow, image-gallery

So I had a page, working perfectly fine with a nice little slider, but then... I put a gallery in which is working fine BUT the slider stopped working. I'm thinking the JS on the gallery is somehow stopping the JS from the slider from working but I have no JS knowledge so I don't know, I deal with HTML and CSS, I will learn JS at some point but for now I am using codrops.

The website is: http://www.maintenancebirmingham.co.uk/ here you can see the slider working fine, if you go to the gallery page: http://www.maintenancebirmingham.co.uk/gallery.html (or just click gallery) then you can see the problem.

If you need any html/css/JS or anything else from the site please let me know, I'm not going to put it all up not because there is just too much and if anyone figures it out without needing it, life is good :)

Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: `"Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'coinslider' "`

Comment: Just a guess but the gallery itself seems to pull in jquery 1.7.1 and you have 1.4.2 included in the head tags, I'd wager having two versions is messing things up a bit

Comment: Is there any way to solve that? The gallery (pulling in 1.7.1) is working fine, the slider, using 1.4.2, is fine on every page but just not on that one so you may be right.

Comment: are you sure the slider was initialized?

Comment: Update coin-slider? I checked it out there is a version that supports jquery 1.9

Comment: If I update it to 1.9 then would the 1.9 jquery not interrupt the gallery which is on 1.7.1?

Comment: that would depend on the conflicts, the coin-slider you have may use jquery code that is deprecated in 1.7 but the gallery may work just fine with 1.9; If you look through the coin slider stuff a bit you may find an older version that was designed closer to jquery 1.7 specs

Comment: Oh ok then, just so you, as advised by someone bellow, I have put the 1.7 jquery above the coin-slider-min.js which has now got the slider working but the gallery has stopped.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like Culyx says, coin-slider-min.js is injecting code in jquery 1.4.2
then below your page jquery 1.7.1 is being loaded, so you override the code injected from coin-slider;

You can try to remove jquery 1.4.2 (if it's possible) and put jquery on the header

or put coin-slider-min.js after jquery 1.7.1

at least seems to be running fine here.

I just reloaded the coin-slider-min.js from your page (with broken code), then I initialize the element with coin slider. This is how I discovered, but don't use it in your current code!

```
function load_js()
{
   var head= document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
   var script= document.createElement('script');
   script.type= 'text/javascript';
   script.src= 'coin-slider.min.js';
   head.appendChild(script);
}
load_js();
//after load
$('#coin-slider').coinslider({ effect: 'rain', delay: 4000, width: 1040, height:435, hoverPause: false });
```

Comment: I have moved the 1.7.1 jquery before the other stuff (I think) and now the slider is working fine and the gallery has stopped, it may be worth looking at what I have done in case I put something in the wrong place.

Comment: so maybe the some stuffs of the page is important use of the jquery 1.4.2 (did u tried to remove it? is there any js errors?), so instead of moving jquery 1.7.1 move coin-slider-min.js after it

Comment: because if you open the console and run the steps that I said, both slider and gallery are working

Comment: Ok I but 1.7.1 back to where it was and put coin-slider-min.js after it but that is not working. So you want me to try removing 1.4.2? Will that not stop the coin slider from working?

Comment: oh don't forget that the script $('#coin-slider').coinslider({ effect: 'rain', delay: 4000, width: 1040, height:435, hoverPause: false }); needs to be also after coin-slider-min.js

Comment: well test if u can remove or not